# the app keep crashing whenever the While loop starts

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have made an `ArrayList` store the numbers from 1 to 10 in Strings, then I wanted to make the numbers in the `ArrayList` displayed in the screen using While loop. But the app keeps crashing when the loop starts.`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_number);
}

ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

{
    // Create an ArrayList of words
    words.add("One");
    words.add("Two");
    words.add("Three");
    words.add("Four");
    words.add("Five");
    words.add("Six");
    words.add("Seven");
    words.add("Eight");
    words.add("Nine");
    words.add("Ten");

    LinearLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);

    // Create a variable to keep track of the current index position
    int index = 0;

    // Keep looping until we've reached the end of the list (which means keep looping
    // as long as the current index position is less than the length of the list)
    while (index < words.size()) {
        // Create a new TextView
        TextView wordView = new TextView(this);

        // Set the text to be word at the current index
        wordView.setText(words.get(index));

        // Add this TextView as another child to the root view of this layout
        rootView.addView(wordView);

        // Increment the index variable by 1
        index++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the error too?  "crashing" is difficult to guess at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialisation is called before the `onCreate` method. so the views are not created yet.

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_number);


    
        // Create an ArrayList of words
        words.add("One");
        words.add("Two");
        words.add("Three");
        words.add("Four");
        words.add("Five");
        words.add("Six");
        words.add("Seven");
        words.add("Eight");
        words.add("Nine");
        words.add("Ten");

        LinearLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);

        // Create a variable to keep track of the current index position
        int index = 0;

        // Keep looping until we've reached the end of the list (which means keep looping
        // as long as the current index position is less than the length of the list)
        while (index < words.size()) {
            // Create a new TextView
            TextView wordView = new TextView(this);

            // Set the text to be word at the current index
            wordView.setText(words.get(index));

            // Add this TextView as another child to the root view of this layout
            rootView.addView(wordView);

            // Increment the index variable by 1
            index++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing this code outside your onCreate function. Put all the code from Array List to index++ inside onCreate function, so when activity is created, it is inside the content.